# Change background color of a checkbox when checked with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a div with a checkbox in it. I've made this http://jsfiddle.net/B7P65/ for reference. I'm trying to replace the parent div with the 'highlight' div, so i thought the toggle div would work. When the checkbox is deselected, I would like the background color to go back to normal (or remove the 'highlight' div). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method incorrectly.  You want to extract the `toggleClass()` method from within the `parent()` method and place it separately.

Try the following update:

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight");
```

Complete:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var actualTime = "";
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hmq65/

Comment: Thanks, I missed the parent logic.

Answer (score 2):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/q3NN2/ **or ANother way** http://jsfiddle.net/KUhFp/

second demo shows how to use using `.is(':checked')` just something extra if you want to use the is checked logic, `:)`

**code**

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var actualTime = "";
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

**code**

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var actualTime = "";
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");

    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely be using the checked method in a different scenario.

Comment: @Vikram Cool, Glad it was useful `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/B7P65/1/

Answer (score 0):

This code works for highlighting when checked and remove class when unchecked.

**JavaScript:**

```
    $('#your table id tr')
    .filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)')
    .addClass('highlight')
    .end()
    .click(function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(':checkbox', this).attr('checked', function() {
        return !this.checked;
    });
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```css
.highlight{
    background-color:green;
}
```